# How to display the list of categories which contain items in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask how to display a list of categories which contain items. Categories without item linked from other table should not be displayed.
Also,categories should be displayed according to the number of items.

Please consider the two tables:

```
   |------- categorytbl----|
   cat_id  |    cat_name
    1      |    Pet
    2      |    Person
    3      |    Places
   -------------------------

   |------ itemstbl -----|
    item_id      item_description     cat_id
     1                John              2
     2                Peter             2
     3                 Cat              1
```

If I am going to query the above table, the output should be:

Pet(1) , Person(2)

And, I should not include Places category since it does not contain any item.

I tried my query:

```
   SELECT * FROM categorytbl a, itemstbl b WHERE a.cat_id=b.cat_id
```

Comment: That is a simple join, as explained by any basic tutorial

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know that.. I'm new to sql

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33599569/1771479) on this similar question: [Using count in where clause : invalid use of group function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599400/using-count-in-where-clause-invalid-use-of-group-function/33599569#33599569).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select all elements from both tables and inner join them so you get only matching results on both sides

```
SELECT cat_name, COUNT(item_id) AS items_count 
FROM categorytbl AS cat
INNER JOIN itemstbl AS item ON cat.cat_id = item.cat_id
GROUP BY cat.cat_id
ORDER BY items_count DESC
```

To get better understanding of how JOINs work in SQL have a look at this picture:

[image]

But as other people have said read the relevent documentation for the RDBMS you're using or a tutorial for SQL that would help you get your head arround it.

Comment: ...order by items_count desc

Comment: One can sort but the provided code is focusing to delivering the results. I'll add it though, Thanks!

Comment: thanks very much...:)

Comment: it helped me too, but wondering how does `COUNT(item_id)` work without alias like `item.item_id`. and grouping by. wishing if someone could explain this query.