# Display the category list even if it does not contain any item

Tags: mysql

In Connection to my question, 
[How to display the list of categories which contain items in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604964/how-to-display-the-list-of-categories-which-contain-items-in-mysql)

I would like to ask how to display the list of category from the items even if the category does not contain any record in itemtbl. Here is my query:

```
SELECT   *, count(*) as cnt
FROM categorytbl LEFT JOIN itemstbl 
ON itemstbl.cat_id=categorytbl.cat_id
GROUP BY  itemstbl.cat_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

**the result is :**

Pet(1)
person(2)

**I want the result to be:**

Pet(1)
person(2)
Places(0)

Comment: How do "Pet", "person", and "Places" relate to your tables?

Comment: Oh, I see... they are all categories.  I just read your other question.

Comment: I want to display the "Places" category even if it contains zero(0) result on itemtbl but I don'w know how.. I am expecting that left join is the solution but was not able to produce exact result.

Comment: That's what I get when I run your query in MySQL with the data you gave.  It shows 1 for ``cnt`` in the "Places" row.

Comment: Could it be that you have ``WHERE itemstbl.item_id IS NOT NULL`` in your query?

Comment: Still got an error. @Chad

Comment: LOL.. i don't think why I received a downvote.. haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110780/discussion-between-chad-and-smz).

Answer (score 0):

After a couple if minutes of fixing this problem, I got this answer:

```
SELECT categorytbl.cat_id AS cat_id , count(itemstbl.cat_id) as cnt 
FROM categorytbl LEFT JOIN itemstbl 
ON itemstbl.cat_id=categorytbl.cat_id 
GROUP BY cat_id 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The result now is:

> Pet(1)  person(2)  Places(0)

The idea is, just Group the cat_id on categorytbl and count the cat_id on itemstbl.